# Javascript for loop new condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

plz check the code below:

```
for(i=0; i-DIL; i++)//see the condition here i-DIL .Is this correct?
 { 


}
```

is the second condition above in for loop correct?if so ,what does that mean?

actual code is:

```
 javascript:R=0;  
 x1=.1; y1=.05;
 x2=.25; y2=.24;
 x3=1.6; y3=.24;
 x4=300; y4=200;
 x5=300; y5=200;
 DI=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
 DIL=DI.length; 
 function A(){for(i=0; i-DIL; i++)//see the condition here i-DIL .Is this correct?
 { 
 DIS=DI[ i ].style;
 DIS.position='absolute';
 DIS.left=(Math.sin(R*x1+i*x2+x3)*x4+x5)+"px"; 
 DIS.top=(Math.cos(R*y1+i*y2+y3)*y4+y5)+"px"}

R++

}
 setInterval('A()',5); void(0);
```

Also can anyone help me describing the reason for placing void(0) at the end of the script?
And U can see that repeatedly image position is set over and over .How can i overcome that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not it's "correct" depends on what exactly you want the `for` loop to do. However, it is valid code, and hinges on the fact that `0` in JavaScript is "falsey", while other numbers are "truthy".

Essentially, when `i` and `DIL` are equal, `i - DIL` equals `0`, which for the purposes of the `for` loop condition is evaluated as `false`, and it stops iterating. Given that `DIL` is the length of a collection, it's an interesting (but technically valid) method of iterating over the entire collection.

It's equivalent to (though I'd say less readable than):

```
for(i=0; i < DIL; i++)
```

Comment: @Lee Kowalkowski also can u tell me the reason to place void(0) at the end of the script and  
also i-DIL is false ,how will the code get executed since i value is 0

Comment: @user2060755 Scratch my previous comment, is this a `href` attribute on a link? The `void(0)` statement returns undefined, its main use is in link `href` attributes using the `javascript:` protocol so that the link doesn't redirect anywhere.

Comment: @MaizerePathak, you have a Bookmarklet/Favelet. That uses a `javascript:` URI (`javascript:` would be a *scheme*, not a protocol), whatever you return in a JavaScript URI will be loaded as a new document (e.g. `javascript:"Hello World!"`).  Unless your JavaScript URI returned `undefined`, in which case no new document is loaded into the browser window.  Without the `void(0)` in your code example, the result of setInterval will be loaded into the browser window, which would be an integer as far as I know.  There's no need to make the `void` keyword look like a function. `void 0;` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

it means  execute code below till `i-DIL != 0`. ie here in your code it will work till `i` reaches `DIL`.

Comment: i mean is this "-" a sign of subtract

Comment: A little context on truthy and falsy values in JavaScript might be useful to OP here as well: http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript

Comment: yes. so here condition checked in for loop will be result of subtraction operation

Comment: @user2060755 yes in JavaScript (and most if not all programming languages) the "-" is an operator to subtract two values.

Comment: @user2060755 i saw you still have doubts. Even if i is 0 i-DIL will evaluate to true till i reaches DIL (ie when i - DIL equals zero). For non zero values condition evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

A for loops **usually** takes:

```
for(variable definition; condition; increment) {}
```

So, you need a condition. However, because Javascripts has loose content types, you don't have to use a *comparison* for it to be `true` or `false`.

```
10 - 1          // = 9 equals true
10 - 9          // = 1 equals true
10 - 10         // = 0 equals false

"legit string"  // equals true
NULL            // equals false
```

However, I do suggest to make an actual comparison just to avoid nasty browsers to break your condition.

```
for(var i = 0; i - DIL > 0; i++) {}
```

Comment: also can u tell me the reason to place void(0) at the end of the script

Comment: also i-DIL is false ,how will the code get executed since i value is 0